# Counterexample for $f$ is strictly increasing ,$ g$ and $f\circ g$ is continous but f is not continous

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I wanted to find counterexample

Counterexample for $f$ is strictly increasing,$ g$ and $f\circ g$ is continuous but $f$ is not continuous

Where f and g are function form $[0,1]\to [0,1]$

How to approach to find such example

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $g(x)=0{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: great Sir...I am always missing such examples...

Comment: But Sir If We want both map as surjective map then is it possible to such  construct map?

Comment: @MathLover No, if $g$ is surjective and continuous, and $f$ is not continuous, then for some $x_0$, we will have $g(x_0)$ be some point of discontinuity of $f$, which means that $f(g(x))$ must be discontinuous at that point. I've glossed over a few details here, but that's the general argument.